# In opengl es is there a way to know when your textures are loaded?

Tags: android, button, opengl-es, textures

I have a Glsurfaceview underneath some xml buttons. When I start my application, the glsurfaceview shows a black screen for a few seconds, presumably because it's loading the textures. The problem is that the button loads first, so I would have a visible button over a black screen until the textures load, then it's no longer a black screen. Is there a way to make the surfaceview and button load at the same time, what's the proper way of doing this?

Comment: Did you end up with an opportunity to have both elements loading simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

Add your Button layout after you added the GLSurface view.

```
 addContentView(mGlView, new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

 // Camera Control
 cameraLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
 View cameraControl = cameraLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_control, null);
 addContentView(cameraControl, new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

This is how I do it and the Button's layout is always on top.
You may also check this link:
http://android-er.blogspot.se/2010/12/add-overlay-on-camera-preview.html

Comment: I don't think actually answers the question he has

Comment: @Sticky, You are right. But the title is a little misleading. As far as I understood, he wants to overlay some buttons over GLSurface view which has nothing to do with textures and other stuffs. Forgive me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

A texture is loaded once you finish your glTexImage2D call

Just make the button invisible when you add it

Then after you've finished all your glTexImage2D calls, make that button visible

FYI, unless you're intentionally loading in your images asynchronously, then for the time you see a black surface view, the UI thread isn't actually moving along